# Group Theory - exercises 12.1 of Beardon Algebra + Geometry

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Suppose a group $G$ contains two elements $a,b$ where $a^{-1}ba=b^2$ and $b^{-1}ab=a^2$. Suppose also that every element of $G$ can be expressed as a product of the elements $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$, taken as often as we wish, in any order and with repetitions allowed. Prove that $a=b=e$.

Progress: Rearranging the two initial conditions we have $ba=abb, ab=baa$.

Multiplying these two together gives $baab=abbbaa$, so $b(b^{-1}ab)b=ab^3a^2$ from which it follows that $b^2=b^3a^2$. Hence $e=ba^2=ab$.

Multiplying in the opposite direction yields $e=ab^2$. As such we have $e=ab=ab^2$ so left multiplying by $a^{-1}$ gives $b^2=b$ which is satisfied only by $b=e$. An exactly similar approach gives $a=e$. Hence $a=b=e$.  Is this correct?

Comment: The last part (with the opposite direction and similar approach) is unnessecary. We have $ab=e$, so $e=ab=ba^2=a^{-1}a^2=a$. Then $b=e$.